Generate migration schema for initial database
I created an entity, and now I wish to generate the migration that will create the table for this entity. How do I do this?
I only see documentation mentioning running migrations for changes; but what about the initial setup of the database?

Once you get into production you'll need to synchronize model changes into the database. Typically, it is unsafe to use synchronize: true for schema synchronisation on production once you get data in your database. Here is where migrations come to help.

In other words: How do I generate the initial schema (prior to any migrations/changes) that I need to run in production to create the initial database with tables?

Doesn't the first migration you create just assume starting from scratch?

@jonrsharpe I wish it did. I can add new migrations, as if I was chaning something in the database, but I am not. I am merly trying to generate the database schema as code, so that will be the first migration every run: "initial database setup".
